# permute a file and print even lines from a second file

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation, python-itertools

I have two input files:

sentances.txt

```
This is a sentance with keyword one two three.
This is a sentance with keyword four five.
This is a sentence with keyword six.
```

keywords.txt

```
one two three
four five
six
```

I want the output files to look like:

permuated-keywords.txt

```
one two three
one three two
two one three
two three one
three one two
three two one
four five
five four
six
```

multiple-sentances.txt

```
This is a sentance with keyword one two three.
This is a sentance with keyword one two three.
This is a sentance with keyword one two three.
This is a sentance with keyword one two three.
This is a sentance with keyword one two three.
This is a sentance with keyword one two three.
This is a sentance with keyword four five.
This is a sentance with keyword four five.
This is a sentence with keyword six.
```

This code runs without error but doesn't put the correct number of lines in multiple-sentances.txt

```
from itertools import permutations

import operator
from collections import Counter
from math import factorial
def npermutations(l):
    num = factorial(len(l))
    mults = Counter(l).values()
    den = reduce(operator.mul, (factorial(v) for v in mults), 1)
    return num / den


with open('sentances.txt', 'r') as longfile:  
   with open('multiple-sentances.txt', 'w') as out2:
      with open('keywords.txt', 'r') as shortfile:
         with open('permuated-keywords.txt', 'w') as out:
            for line in shortfile:
               perm=('\n'.join(map(' '.join, permutations(line.split()))))
               numofperms=npermutations(line.split())
               out.write(perm)
               out.write('\n')
               for line in longfile:
                  for i in range(numofperms):
                     out2.write(line)
```

~

Comment: It is not at all obvious what is your intended result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, the following code could help you. It appears not so "elegant", but it's working.

```
import itertools
import os

with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'keywords.txt'), 'r') as keyfile:
    keywords_list = keyfile.readlines()
    keywords_perm = []
    new_file = []
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'sentences.txt'), 'r') as sentences:
        sentences_list = sentences.readlines()
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'multiple-sentances.txt'), 'w') as new:
        i = 0
        for key in keywords_list:
            perm = itertools.permutations(key.split())
            for element in perm:
                keywords_perm.append(element)
                if sentences_list[i].find(" ".join(key.split())) != -1:
                    new.write(sentences_list[i][:sentences_list[i].find(" ".join(key.split()))] + " ".join(key.split()) + "\n")
                else:
                    i += 1
                    new.write(sentences_list[i][:sentences_list[i].find(" ".join(key.split()))] + " ".join(key.split()) + "\n")
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'permutated-keywords.txt'), 'w') as out:
        for i in range (0, len(keywords_perm)):
            out.write(" ".join(keywords_perm[i]) + "\n")
```